# Excel2010/VBA: Store and Usage of Worksheet Variable during Userform Session

Tags: vba, excel

- In Worksheet1 is a button that is calling a Userform
- I want to use the current Worksheet during the Userform Session but I'm not able to use this.
- I want to use a variable for further usage.
- The Button on Worksheet1 is Calling this Macro

```vb
Option Explicit
Public GlbVarBaseSheet As String
------------
Sub Formularaufruf_Worksheet1()
    GlbVarBaseSheet = ActiveSheet.Name            
    with Userform1
    .MultiPage1.Value = 1
    .Show 0
End With
End Sub
```

Within the Userform, there's a Sub Called Uebernahme, which fills out the Textboxes reading the column number which is stored in the .tag of the TextBox.

How can I Use the Worksheet Variable in this line to use is during the Userform Session: This is not working and I don't know why.

```vb
With Workbooks("KVP.xlsm").Worksheets(GlbVarBaseSheet)
```

The Full Sub:

```vb
Sub Uebernahme()

Dim Zeilenindex As Long
Dim OBcB As MSForms.Control
Dim VarTypeName As String
Sheets(GlbVarBaseSheet).Activate
'
'
'
Workbooks("KVP.xlsm").ActiveSheet.Rows(spinbutton1.Value).Activate
Zeilenindex = spinbutton1.Value
'
'
With Workbooks("KVP.xlsm").Worksheets(GlbVarBaseSheet) 

    If .Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Value <> "" Then
        For Each OBcB In MultiPage1.SelectedItem.Controls
            VarTypeName = TypeName(OBcB)
            If OBcB.Tag <> "" Then
                Select Case VarTypeName
                    Case Is <> "Checkbox"
                        'OBcB.Value = .cells(Left(OBcB.Tag, 1) & ActiveCell.Row)
                        OBcB.Value = .Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Int(Left(OBcB.Tag, 1))).Value
                End Select
            End If
        Next
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: How exactly is `With Workbooks("KVP.xlsm").Worksheets(GlbVarBaseSheet) ` not working - do you get an error?  Which one?  What is the value of `GlbVarBaseSheet` at this line when it fails (set a breakpoint there to check)?

Comment: Is the `Public GlbVarBaseSheet As String` routine in a worksheet code module? If so you need to either move it to a normal module, or refer to `Sheet1.GlbVarBaseSheet` when using the variable from other modules (where `Sheet1` represents the codename for your worksheet).

Comment: Don´t know why.. but now.. it works without any Problem. thx. for reply!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
dim GlbVarBaseSheet as Worksheet
```